# NHibernate 3.2 By Code (Conformist) ClassMapping For a Dictionary Property

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

Assume I have a class "SomeClass" that has a lookup dictionary:
DataDictionary;

I currently have a mapping in SomeClass.hbm.xml like this:

```
<class name="SomeClass>

  <id name="ID" type="System.Guid">
    <generator class="guid" />
  </id>

  <map name="DictionaryProperty" table="SomeClass_Data">
    <key column="SomeClassID" />
    <index column="Key" type="System.String" />
    <element column="Value" type="System.String" />
  </map>

</class>
```

I want to use NHibernate's new (version 3.2) By Code mappings.  How would I map the dictionary property above?

Currently I have:

```
  public class SomeClassMap :ClassMap<SomeClass>
  {

     public SomeClassMap()
     {
        Id(x => x.ID, mapping => mapping.Generator(Generators.Guid));
        Map(x = x.DictionaryProperty, mapping =>
           {
              mapping.Key(k => k.Column("SomeClassID"));
              mapping.Table("SomeClassData");
           });
     }

  }
```

Mostly I am at a loss for how to specify the equivalent of the index and the element for a dictionary mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each part of the dictionary mapping requires a separate delegate:

```
Map(x => x.DictionaryProperty,
    mapping =>
    {
        mapping.Key(k => k.Column("SomeClassID"));
        mapping.Table("SomeClassData");
    },
    mapping => mapping.Element(k => k.Column("Key")),
    mapping => mapping.Element(k => k.Column("Value")));
```

The first `Element` is the `map-key` (`index` is obsolete for `map`), and the second one is the `element`.

Comment: "index is obsolete for map"...the official documentation makes no mention of this =(

Comment: Yeah... I was working on a doc patch for that, but lost it. Anyway, `index` still works, it's just that `map-key` is preferred.